# Need help extracting text while excluding other characters

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Here the string:

```
Acanthite (Y: 1855) 02.BA.35 [18] [19] [20]
(IUPAC: Disilver sulfide)
Acetamide (1974-039) 10.AA.20 [21] [22] [23]
(IUPAC: Acetic acid amide)
Achalaite (2013-103) 04.?? [24] [no] [no]
Achavalite (Y: 1939
```

Here's my regex:

```
([^B35\[1-9\] 0:Y\(\)\n-.?])+
```

I've also tried:

```
^[a-z]+
```

What I would like outputted as a multi line is:
(No particular programming language used)

```
Acanthite
Acetamide
Achalaite
Achavalite
```

Comment: Why are you using `[^B35\[1-9\]`

Comment: Here is another regex: [`(?im)^([a-z]+).*(\r?\n[^a-z].*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/zL3oU0/3). If you replace with `$1`, you will get a multiline text with just words at the beginning of lines only.

Comment: @strivizhev, that second solution is perfect. It works. Could you explain the solution for me. I can see that you have three groups that I could have accessed with \1\2\3.

Comment: Oh, fortunately, I did not close the page: you made a typo in my username and I did not get any notifications. I will post the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a multiline string as input and you need to remove everything but the first words on the lines starting with Latin letters, you can use the following trick:

- Match and capture the first word on a line (thus, you need `^` start-of-string anchor together with `/m` multiline modifier)
- Match the rest of the line and all the subsequence lines that do not start with a Latin letter.

The regex is:

```
(?im)^([a-z]+).*(\r?\n[^a-z].*)*
```

See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL3oU0/3)

The `(?im)` is the inline representation of `m` multiline and `i` ignorecase flags.

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of line
- `([a-z]+)` - 1 or more Latin letters
- `.*` - the rest of line
- `(\r?\n[^a-z].*)*` - 0 or more sequences of...

  - `\r?\n` - newlines
  - `[^a-z]` - a symbol other than a Latin letter
  - `.*` - the rest of line

Note that to match and remove the non-welcome lines from the start of string, you need to add the `(?:[^a-z].*\r?\n)*` subpattern to the beginning:

```
(?im)^(?:[^a-z].*\r?\n)*([a-z]+).*(\r?\n[^a-z].*)*
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL3oU0/4)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0):

Just add case insensitive modifier. or You need to include `A-Z` inside the character class.

```
/^[a-z]+/im
```

or

```
(?im)^[a-z]+
```

or

```
(?m)^[a-zA-Z]+
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

A\w*e\s

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/hH8xD4/1